# Does any Common Lisp function return 3 values?

Tags: return-value, common-lisp

Does any Common Lisp (builtin) function return more than 2 values?  I know many that return 2, but I can't think of one that returns 3.

(I saw a comment here about returning more than 2 values, and tried to think of a case where CL did this, but can't.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a get-setf-expansion function. It returns 5 values.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, such functions exist. Here is the complete list of functions in the COMMON-LISP package that return exactly three values, as declared in SBCL source code:

```
COMPILE                                 required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
INTEGER-DECODE-FLOAT                    required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
COMPILE-FILE                            required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
GET-PROPERTIES                          required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION              required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
DECODE-FLOAT                            required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
RENAME-FILE                             required: 3, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
```

In addition, the following functions return a constant number of values greater than three:

```
DECODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME                   required: 9, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
GET-DECODED-TIME                        required: 9, optional: 0, rest?: NIL
```

These functions return a variable number of values, hence possibly more than three:

```
NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD                    required: 0, optional: 0, rest?: T
NO-NEXT-METHOD                          required: 0, optional: 0, rest?: T
VALUES                                  required: 0, optional: 0, rest?: T

(I've omitted some functions from this list where SBCL does not declare
a values type explicitly.  get-setf-expansion is one of them.)
```

Explanations of the columns: `required` is minimum number of return values for these functions, `optional` a fixed number of return values which SBCL thinks might or might not be returned, `rest?` indicates that a variable number of values is expected.  (Only `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1` actually use &optional, don't ask me why.)

And just for fun, here is the source code I used to come up with these tables:

```
(do-external-symbols (sym :common-lisp)                                         
  (when (fboundp sym)                                                           
    (multiple-value-bind (required optional rest)                               
        (let ((fun-type (sb-int:info :function :type sym)))                     
          (etypecase fun-type                                                   
            (sb-kernel:fun-type                                                 
             (let ((returns                                                     
                    (sb-kernel:fun-type-returns fun-type)))                     
               (etypecase returns                                               
                 (sb-kernel:values-type                                         
                  (values (length (sb-kernel:values-type-required returns))     
                          (length (sb-kernel:values-type-optional returns))     
                          (sb-kernel:values-type-rest returns)))                
                 (sb-kernel:named-type                                          
                  (if (sb-kernel:named-type-name returns)                       
                      (values 1 0 t)                                          
                      (values 0 0 nil))))))                                     
            (t                                                                  
             (values 0 0 t))))                                                  
      (format t                                                                 
              "~A~40Trequired: ~D, optional: ~D, rest?: ~A~%"                   
              sym                                                               
              required optional rest))))
```

Answer (score 7):

decode-universal-time returns nine values.

Answer (score 2):

[VALUES](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_values.htm#values) and [VALUES-LIST](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_vals_l.htm#values-list), among others.